# How to perform a two column lookup and then sum the values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to look up two values in my table. The winner and withdrawal values. In the example below, if the person's name equals "Brad Hughes" and the Withdrawal value equals "No" then I want to sum all of the Prize values.

Essentially, what I am doing is checking if they withdrew their prize winnings and if not, come up with a balance.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Use SUMIFS(): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you. How could I nest that into the formula though?

Comment: You don't nest it.  It would be the full formula:  `=SUMIFS($E$5:$E$46,$B$5:$B$46,J5,$F$5:$F$46,P5)`

Comment: If still have issues try this video on how to use the formula. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZuBNWMh7VM

Comment: I know how to use the formula.  I do not need the video.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you! This did the trick!